# Restrict unauthorised access in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have various applications in a Django project, but I only want users who are logged in to be able to access those pages. How can I restrict access to every pages except the login page which is my main page. For instance, mywebsite.com/home/user should be only available to user and if someone types in that it should redirect them to mywebsite.com

Currently I have two apps, main and Home, I am using *ClassBased* views on my Home app how can I restrict access to all my pages except login page and show a message as well?

I want to create a template that users can see other user profile details but not change or edit them. How can I do those above steps

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) you can decorate the class based views with @*login_required*

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ClassBasedView(View): 
    ...
    ...
```

Since you are using class based view, you need to add method decorator, else you can use @logine_required directly.

And the other part in the question is again a separate one from this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try This, In very simple way

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse()
```

using **@login_required** means user have to login to access that view

Or If you you Want to use class then try this

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class RestrictedView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'foo/restricted.html'
    raise_exception = True 
    permission_denied_message = "You are not allowed here."
```

Comment: Thanks! yes I tried this an it worked. Thanks for your help